# Bulk data load not loading all records because of constraint, but I don't know why

Tags: sql-server

I have to bulk load data from an older system(Caché I think) to a SQL Server.  I was handling the creating of the SQL Server DB and table, and another person was handling getting me the old data into a delimited file that I would load in using SSIS package.  Once the data load was done, he had an interface created which would constantly feed any old records into the SQL table.  For his interface, he sent me a schema of what his interface was expecting the table to look like, which was this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CASENOTE](
    [PAS_INT_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CASENOTE] [varchar](14) NOT NULL,
    [DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CURRENT_STATUS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DATE_ALLOCATED] [date] NULL,
    [DATE_PLACED] [date] NULL,
    [DATE_WITHDRAWN] [date] NULL,
    [STORAGE_COMMENT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PAS_VALID] [varchar](3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [IX_CASENOTE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CASENOTE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

However, I have written an application to search this data, and I had added an extra field to my table, CASENOTE_ID.  So I wanted this added to the table too, so I changed his script to add that, which looked like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CASENOTE](
    [CASENOTE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PAS_INT_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CASENOTE] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CURRENT_STATUS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DATE_ALLOCATED] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATE_PLACED] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATE_WITHDRAWN] [datetime] NULL,
    [STORAGE_COMMENT] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PAS_VALID] [varchar](3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CASENOTE_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CASENOTE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [IX_CASENOTE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CASENOTE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

So that's all fine I think, I go to load the data in - the are 1.6 million records, but when the SSIS package tried to load them, it sent around 200,000 to the error file.  It always seems to send this same amount to the error file that it couldn't insert into the table.  So, I removed the original constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT [IX_CASENOTE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CASENOTE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And this worked!  All of the data inserted perfect.

So, the reason for this question is to ask why.  Can anyone help me understand what happened here, why that constraint prevented 200,000 records being loaded, and why removing it allowed them?  I'm not a DBA, and everything I have done so far is learning as I go, so I don't understand constraints too well, or their implications, I've just been learning what I need to get the job done.  Does anybody know what happened here?

ps. figuring out how to create and run the SSIS package and seeing those numbers go up was really fun and cool.

Comment: You defined [CASENOTE] to be unique, so you mustn't have any duplicates in the column.

Comment: When I removed the constraint, and got all of the data to load without the constraint, I did a search for duplicates, and only found around 200.

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` value in column `[CASENOTE]` ?

Comment: If you're bulk inserting, how many records are rejected depends on the batch size SSIS ultimately ends up using. An entire batch of rows is committed or rejected on its own, even if there is only a single problematic row in there. You can tune this, but never so precisely that it will only reject the problematic rows -- that requires not bulk inserting at all, but doing the inserts one by one. In such a case it can more efficient to add a step before that finds and removes the duplicates with a lookup or sort before doing the inserting proper.